# Referring to a column in csv file python

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

I am new to python so sorry it this seems a little silly.

I have a CSV file where the first column is 'letter' followed by 150 letters, that is 150 rows of different letters of the alphabet, then another 16 columns with different info. I want to be able to refer to the first column, letter:

```
with open('file.csv') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    filedata = [r for r in reader]    
print(filedata[0].letter)
```

As seen above, i want to be able to refer to the first column of the file. So:

```
print(filedata[0])
```

Prints all the columns with that row of data, whereas i just want to refer to the first column, it's letter. More specifically i want to count all the letters in the file,

eg. output:

number of y's: 23, number of x's: 12 etc...

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pandas is a really powerful package in python that helps you do all this.You can handle data with great ease. For example importing your csv file and accessing the first column can get as simple as this:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('file.csv')
```

here df stands for dataframe. I suggest you readup about it [here](https://www.datacamp.com/community/tutorials/pandas-tutorial-dataframe-python).
You can print the first column in this way:

```
print(df['letter'])
```

[This](http://pythonforengineers.com/introduction-to-pandas/) is an amazing place to get started on pandas.
To print the number of y's and x's you can look at Groupby and aggregate functions and there [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.agg.html).